# How MapDB is different from other Key-Value store like RocksDb and LMDB?

Tags: database, key-value-store, microbenchmark, rocksdb, lmdb

I am testing the benchmark results of LMDB,RocksDB and MapDB. MapDB has an implementation to access the store (HTree and BTree) but other database doesn't provide any. Does this provide any significant advantage to MapDB from other database in any way? Or Other databases provide any implementations also?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't.

It also depends on what you are trying to do. HTree gives you O(1) lookups but you forgo the ability to do a range scan

Rocksdb gives you a LSM instead of a BTree but the API for both is the same